# gjs How to read a socket stream in Gnome Shell Extension using g_data_input_stream_read_line_async

Tags: javascript, sockets, asynchronous, gnome, gjs

I'm trying to write a Gnome-Shell extension that communicates with Arduino through a Socket Server. The Server and Arduino are running fine, but I'm stuck at the extension code that listens for incoming Server messages.

Since I need a non blocking approach, using [read_line_async](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDataInputStream.html#g-data-input-stream-read-line-async) seems perfect.

However I can't manage to get it to work. Here's what i got so far (relevant part):

```
    let sockClient, sockConnection, output_reader, receivedline;

// connect to socket
    sockClient = new Gio.SocketClient();
    sockConnection = sockClient.connect_to_host("127.0.0.1:21567", null, null);


// read server socket

    output_reader = new Gio.DataInputStream({ base_stream: sockConnection.get_input_stream() });

    output_reader.read_line_async(0, null, _SocketRead, null);


// callback

    function _SocketRead() {

        let [lineout, charlength, error] = output_reader.read_line_finish();

        receivedline = lineout;
        // process received data

    }
```

The async function is started just fine and also `_SocketRead` gets called, when there's a line received from the server,  but it fails to read the data with `read_line_finish()`.

I'm completely new to gio and Extension development so I might just miss something obvious.

To me it seems like `read_line_finish()` may be missing it's [GAsyncResult](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAsyncResult.html) parameter, but i've got no clue on how to implement it.

EDIT:

The Callback function and read_line_finish() were missing their parameters.
Thanks to Gerd's answer I was able to make it work. Helped me to figure out the example linked in the [GIO Reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAsyncResult.html) under "Description". So here is the working code for comparison:

```
    let sockClient, sockConnection, output_reader, receivedline;

// connect to socket
    sockClient = new Gio.SocketClient();
    sockConnection = sockClient.connect_to_host("127.0.0.1:21567", null, null);


// read server socket

    output_reader = new Gio.DataInputStream({ base_stream: sockConnection.get_input_stream() });

    output_reader.read_line_async(0, null, _SocketRead, null);


// callback

    function _SocketRead(gobject, async_res, user_data) {

        let [lineout, charlength, error] = gobject.read_line_finish(async_res);

        receivedline = lineout;
        // process received data

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also new to GJS but a solid understanding of programming language led me to the following partial solution: According to [the Gio DataStream reference](http://www.roojs.com/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/gjs/Gio.DataInputStream.html#expand) You have to provide all required parameters to the method, e.g.,

```
let asyncResult = new Gio.SimpleAsyncResult();
let length;
let lineout = output_reader.read_line_finish(asyncResult, length);
```

HTH,
  Gerd

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me to get to the problem ;)

Comment: Great, would you mind to post your final solution to let others look into it if they stumble about a similar problem?

Comment: Sure. I already edited my initial question with the updated code.
The complete extension for Gnome3 can be found here: [extensions.gnome/ArduinoControl](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/894/arduino-control/)